# Using this.elementref.nativeElement.remove() will cause security risk

Tags: angular

I am using this.elementref.nativeElement.remove() through a custom directive in our angular application to show hide few fields. Can it cause any security risk?

Comment: Why do you need to add/remove the elements in question from DOM like this? This is not the recommended way. Why not use the built-in structural directives for this?

Comment: Agreed, But we have some requirement of role-based and country specific show hide . So rather than using multiple condition checking and using *ngIf . we thought of handling it from one directive. . Modifying dom using elementref can cause security risk that I know, but we are only removing unnecessary fields . Do you think there will be security risk .

Comment: If direct access to native elements is supported that is, if your application is not running in as a web worker, I guess you can. Though you can look into using `Renderer2` API available in `@angular/core`. It provides methods such as `removeChild()` (For cases where you want to remove a child node from DOM) and `setAttribute()` (For cases where you want to disable specific fields) Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#description)

Comment: change the question to appropriate title